# Recording Video on iphone and outputting to 16x9 aspect ratio

Tags: ios, iphone, video, aspect-ratio

Is it possible to record in 16x9 aspect ratio?

How do i output a recorded video from my iphone to 16:9 aspect ratio.

I currently have this which records but letter box when i share it and use it in another video player.

I am using titanium

```
Titanium.Media.showCamera({

        success : function(event) {
            Ti.API.debug("video was taken");
        },
        cancel : function() {
        },
        error : function(error) {
            var a = Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({
                title : 'Camera'
            });
            if (error.code == Titanium.Media.NO_CAMERA) {
                a.setMessage('Please run this test on device');
            } else {
                a.setMessage('Unexpected error: ' + error.code);
            }
            a.show();
        },
        mediaTypes : Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO,
        videoMaximumDuration : 600000,
        videoQuality : Ti.Media.QUALITY_MEDIUM,
        //videoQuality : Ti.Media.QUALITY_640x480,
    });
```

Can anyone give some more information on this?

I have been researching but still cannot find a solution, i have been looking into ways to convert the uploaded 4:3 video to 16:9 video with handbrake but this just does not seem to work for me.
I have been through a few of these formats http://finearts.uvic.ca/sim/tutorials/final_cut_pro/video_res.html but still confused.

Help ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, as you are linking to a final cut pro tutorial for external editing. Are you saying the library (Titanium) you are using doesn't have a 16:9 output setting, or you want to convert its 4:3 ratio output in an external tool? If the former, then you can use look up whatever the Titanium video output settings are, or use apple standard code, if the latter, then I would google for video editing software, as there's a ton of them.

Apple has an iOS vidcap reference project called [**AVCam**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html), and the standard [**AVCaptureSession**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureSession) reference docs have a preset for 1920 by 1080: `AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080`. Otherwise, it looks like you're just looking for a list of Titanium videoQuality presets like `Ti.Media.QUALITY_HIGH`, or `Ti.Media.QUALITY_1280x720`, etc.